# how to make multiple populate

Tags: node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I have a double reference in a model file:
[image]

I tried to extract it using the following code:
[image]

Then I tried to show it on the page using handlebars:

[image]

However, the page doesn't show the role's name.
Do you have any idea regarding how can I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mongoose's [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document), I would try adding `.execPopulate()` after `.populate('role')`. Also, I would consider using async/await.